# How to show metabox on page if it is using a template

Tags: theme-development, pages, page-template, child-theme

I was creating metaboxes for a special kind of pages. But i got stuck when showing metaboxes to the pages only who currently have the template 'Sky'.
my template file name is sky-template.php and holds this code.

```
/*
Template Name: Sky
*/
```

And I am adding metaboxes using this function.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add() {
    add_meta_box( 'sky_page_excerpt', 'SkyScraper Page Excerpt and Links', 'sky_page_excerpts', 'page', 'advanced', 'high' );
}
```

I want to add the metaboxes only to pages with template sky. How will i do that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the page-specific meta box hook & accept the `$post` object that's passed to it - then you can check if it currently has a page template of `sky-template.php`.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', function ( $post ) {
    if ( $post->_wp_page_template === 'sky-template.php' ) {
        add_meta_box( 'sky_page_excerpt', 'SkyScraper Page Excerpt and Links', 'sky_page_excerpts', 'page', 'advanced', 'high' );
    }
});
```

**Note:** this will only work on submit/refresh i.e. when you first (de)select the template when editing, you'll need to save changes and have the page reload for the meta box to take affect.